# Dynamic URL routing for a class-based view

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I want to turn a function view into a class-based view.

Here is the View & URL path that I have right now.

View:

```
def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html)
```

URL Path:

```
path('customer/<str:pk>/, views.customer, name='customer')
```

What would the proper syntax be to turn this view into a class-based view.
I am mainly curious about how to access the primary key here using a class-based view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Detail View.

in your views.py

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Customer

class CustomerDetails(DetailView):
    model = Customer 
    template_name = 'customerdetail.html'   #deafaults to customer_detail.html
```

in urls.py

```
path('customer/<int:pk>', views.CustomerDetails.as_view(), name='customer')
```

the context that will be passed to customerdetail.html template will have the default name 'object'. access the fields of customer instance by {{object.<field_name>}}.
You can override the attributes and methods of DetailView.

for moreinfo : [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control in your view you can use generic View

```
from django.views.generic.detail import View
from .models import Customer

class CustomerDetails(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        return render(self.request, 'accounts/customer.html)
```

urls.py

```
path('customer/<int:pk>', views.CustomerDetails.as_view(), name='customer')
```

arguments found in the url are stored in `**kwargs`